# Creating a view of a list with a new column

Tags: sharepoint-designer, microsoft-access

I have a Sharepoint Linked List, linked to an Access table. I have employee identification numbers among other things stored in this table and created a new column which contained a formula to generate a URL to search for said employee on the directory of employees.

This works fine on Sharepoint but causes data issues when it is relayed back to Access.

As these links are generated from the identification numbers, my question is simple. Can I have a list linked between Sharepoint and Access with these id numbers, and create a view of this list with an additional column containing the links calculating using these numbers, which is not relayed back to Access? And if so, how!

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using? Also have you looked into Access Services (service application)?

Comment: Using Sharepoint 2010. And no, I haven't looked into (or even heard) of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link out. http://onehundredwatt.wordpress.com/2012/10/22/introducing-sharepoint-access-services/

Basically you will be publishing the current Access 2010 database to a Web database that is hosted in SharePoint, that way you can control the data in the web database, and it will be better integration with SharePoint.